# Convert csv to RDD

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I tried the accepted solution in [How do I convert csv file to rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd), I want to print out all the users except "om":

```
val csv = sc.textFile("file.csv")  // original file
val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim)) //lines in rows
val header = new SimpleCSVHeader(data.take(1)(0)) // we build our header with the first line
val rows = data.filter(line => header(line,"user") != "om") // filter the header out
val users = rows.map(row => header(row,"user")
users.collect().map(user => println(user))
```

but I got an error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: user
```

I try to debug it and find the `index` attributes in `header` look like this:
[image]

Since I'm new to spark and scala, does this mean that `user` is already in a `Map`? Then why the `key not found` error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. In the REPL it returns: `Array[String] = Array(user, daniel, 3754978)`. BTW, I guess you still would like to filter out the header by doing `data.filter(line => header(line,"user") != "user"))`

Comment: could you add the first lines of the data in the file?

Comment: @maasg, Thanks for your comments. I found out my mistake, it's not the problem with spark/scala, it's the mistake make when I created the csv, I will explain more in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I found out my mistake. It's not related to Spark/Scala. When I created the example csv, I use command in R:

```
df <- data.frame(user=c('om','daniel','3754978'),topic=c('scala','spark','spark'),hits=c(120,80,1))
write.csv(df, "df.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

but `write.csv` will add `"` around factors by default, so that's why the map can't find key `user` because `"user"` is the real key, using

```
write.csv(df, "df.csv",quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten the sample code to remove the header method.
IMO, this example provides a step by step walkthrough that is easier to follow. [Here is a more detailed explanation](http://carminedimascio.com/2015/02/apache-spark-convert-csv-to-rdd/).

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val csv = sc.textFile("/path/to/your/file.csv")

  // split / clean data
  val headerAndRows = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(_.trim))
  // get header
  val header = headerAndRows.first
  // filter out header
  val data = headerAndRows.filter(_(0) != header(0))
  // splits to map (header/value pairs)
  val maps = data.map(splits => header.zip(splits).toMap)
  // filter out the 'om' user
  val result = maps.filter(map => map("user") != "om")
  // print result
  result.foreach(println)
}
```