# How to read the csv and convert to RDD in sparkR

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

As i am a R programmer i want to use R as a interface to spark, with the sparkR package i installed sparkR in R.

I'm new to sparkR. I want to perform some operations on particular data in a CSV record.  I'm trying to read a csv file and convert it to rdd.

```
This is the code i did:
sc <- sparkR.init(master="local") # created spark content
data <- read.csv(sc, "/home/data1.csv")
#It throws an error, to use read.table

Data i have to load and convert - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj78x.png

if am wrong, how to read this data in csv and convert to RDD in sparkR
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is the header line, if you remove this line, it should work.

[How do I convert csv file to rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd)

--edited--

With this code you can test Sparkr with CSVs, but you need to remove the header line in your CSV file.

```
lines <- textFile(sc, "/home/data1.csv") 
csvElements <- lapply(lines, function(line) { 
#line represent each CSV line i. e. strsplit(line, ",") is useful 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i want the code in R, if possible can you write the code and show.

Comment: Arun:  I think what @Alvaro says is that you have to strip the header of the CSV file when you export it, before reading it.

Comment: lines <- textFile(sc, "/home/data1.csv")
csvElements <- lapply(lines, function(line) { 
 #line represent each CSV line i. e. strsplit(line, ",") is useful
})

@pconcepcion :)

Answer (score 0):

In the recent SparkR version (2.0+)

```
read.df(path, source = "csv")
```

In Spark 1.x

```
read.df(sc, path, source = "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

with

```
spark.jars.packages  com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This below code will let you read a csv with header . All the best

```
val csvrdd = spark.read.options(“header”,”true”).csv(filename)
```