# Optimal solution for getting the header from CSV with Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I would like to know what is the optimal solution for getting the header with from a CSV file with Spark? My aproach was:

`def getHeader(data: RDD[String]): String = {
    data.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2==0).map(x=>x._1).take(1).mkString("")
  }`

Thanks.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take the first element of the RDD.

```
val header = rdd.take(1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to spark and I was afraid that due to partitions the first element (take(1) or first method)  will not return always the header.