# How to split rows of a Spark RDD by Deliminator

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapr

I am trying to split data in Spark into the form of an RDD of `Array[String]`. Currently I have loaded the file into an RDD of `String`.

`> val csvFile = textFile("/input/spam.csv")`

I would like to split on a a `,` deliminator.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: @ipoteka: I have gone through this link , but couldnt find anything for CSV file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd

Comment: @ipoteka: Thnx but can you please write it in code, as I am relativity new I unable to understand it.

Comment: If you have a tight deadline, I suggest you research and work on the subject instead of waiting for an answer. The links provided contain code. Go through that, try it out and ask new questions if necessary. 'Plz zend me de codez' is frowned upon'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
val csvFile = textFile("/input/spam.csv").map(line => line.split(","))
```

returns you `RDD[Array[String]]`.

If you need first column as one `RDD` then using `map` function return only first index from Array:

```
  val firstCol = csvFile.map(_.(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but my first line contains the column header, which I would like to exclude and would like to use it for schema definition.

Comment: check this link [how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) library which is able to parse your file considering headers and allow you to specify the delimitor. Also, it makes a pretty good job at infering the schema. I'll let you read the documentation to discover the plenty of [options](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features) at your disposal.

This may look like this :

```
sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("delimiter","your delimitor")
.load(pathToFile)
```

Be aware, this returns a DataFrame that you may have to convert to an rdd using `.rdd` function.

Of course, you will have to load the package into the driver for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create spark session
val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
        .master("local")
        .appName("Spark CSV Reader")
        .getOrCreate;

// read csv
val df = spark.read
         .format("csv")
         .option("header", "true") //reading the headers
         .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
         .option("delimiter", ",")
         .load("/your/csv/dir/simplecsv.csv")

// convert dataframe to rdd[row]
val rddRow = df.rdd
// print 2 rows
rddRow.take(2)

// convert df to rdd[string] for specific column
val oneColumn = df.select("colName").as[(String)].rdd
oneColumn.take(2)

// convert df to rdd[string] for multiple columns
val multiColumn = df.select("col1Name","col2Name").as[(String, String)].rdd
multiColumn.take(2)
```