# Spark - create RDD of (label, features) pairs from CSV file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

I have a CSV file and want to perform a simple LinearRegressionWithSGD on the data.

A sample data is as follow (the total rows in the file is 99 including labels) and the objective is to predict the ***y_3*** variable:

```
y_3,x_6,x_7,x_73_1,x_73_2,x_73_3,x_8
2995.3846153846152,17.0,1800.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
2236.304347826087,17.0,1432.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2001.9512195121952,35.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
992.4324324324324,17.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
4386.666666666667,26.0,1430.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1335.9036144578313,17.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
1097.560975609756,17.0,1100.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,5.0
3526.6666666666665,26.0,1432.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,12.0
506.8421052631579,17.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2095.890410958904,35.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
720.0,35.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
2416.5,17.0,1432.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
3306.6666666666665,35.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,12.0
6105.974025974026,35.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,25.0
1400.4624277456646,35.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,5.0
1414.5454545454545,26.0,1430.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
5204.68085106383,26.0,1800.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,25.0
1812.2222222222222,17.0,1800.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
2763.5928143712576,35.0,1100.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,12.0
```

I already read the data with the following command:

```
val data = sc.textFile(datadir + "/data_2.csv");
```

When I want to create a RDD of (label, features) pairs with the following command:

```
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
    }.cache()
```

[image: indicated error in the output]

So I can not continue for training a model, any help?

P.S. I run the spark with Scala IDE in Windows 7 x64.

Comment: You need to filter out the header. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd/24307475#24307475

Comment: Thanks, I take the header out but now when I use: val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
    }.cache(), an error "value split is not a member of Array[String]" occurs. Can you help me?

Comment: You are doing `parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)`, not sure why you are splitting by spaces, as the input does not have them. Also, you changed your code, I don't see the error you mention above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of efforts I found out the solution. The first problem was related to the header rows and the second was related to mapping function. Here is the complete solution:

```
//To read the file
val csv = sc.textFile(datadir + "/data_2.csv");

//To find the headers
val header = csv.first;

//To remove the header
val data = csv.filter(_(0) != header(0));

//To create a RDD of (label, features) pairs
val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
    }.cache()
```

I hope it can save your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you read in your file the first line

```
y_3,x_6,x_7,x_73_1,x_73_2,x_73_3,x_8
```

Is also read and transformed in your `map` function so you're trying to call `toDouble` on `y_3`. You need to filter out the first row and do the learning using the remaining rows.

Comment: Thanks, I take the header out but now when I use: val parsedData = data.map { line =>
    val parts = line.split(',')
    LabeledPoint(parts(0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(parts(1).split(' ').map(_.toDouble)))
    }.cache(), an error "value split is not a member of Array[String]" occurs. Can you help me?