# Pyspark failed to connect to executor

Tags: apache-spark

I have an issue with apache-spark.
I work with yarn-client mode.

This is my configuration :

```
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
conf.set("spark.driver.cores", "4")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "3")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
conf.set("spark.num.executor", "8")
conf.set("spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries", "20")
```

This is my code:

I have 2 dataframes, df and other_df.
I first inner join the 2 dataframes to get a filtered one based on ID.
I then aggregate to compute mean of CA per month (df_agg).
I then would like to collect() or take(12) to plot a graphic.
An error occurs when I collect()

```
#---  inner join to select the right segment ---#
new_df = (other_df
  .join(df, df.ID == other_df.ID
       )
  )
#--- aggregate the mean per month ---#
df_agg = (new_df
          .groupBy("month")
          .avg('CA')
          )
#--- collect() ---#
data = df_agg.collect()
x, y = zip(*data)
```

I get this error message in Spark:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o824.javaToPython.
: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
.....

at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate.doExecute(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.javaToPython(DataFrame.scala:1582)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$TreeNodeException: execute, tree:
......
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate.doExecute(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(Exchange.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoin.doExecute(BroadcastHashJoin.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.TungstenProject.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.TungstenAggregate$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(TungstenAggregate.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.errors.package$.attachTree(package.scala:48)
    ... 35 more
```

and these are the error messages in Spark UI:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to <executor> +details
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to <executor> 
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:321)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
```

I have trouble reading the error logs. 
I tried to increase number of executors (up to 8), increase the shuffle.io.maxRetries (up to 20). I have also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074288/getting-error-in-spark-executor-lost), which is useful but I have trouble understanding which parameter to tune.

Especially because sometimes the job succeeds and the next time it fails...

I then changed configuration with:

```
conf.set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "600")
```

But it did not work either.

Does anyone have a clue about that issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could set spark.sql.broadcastTimeout to a value greater than the default of 300s.

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind detailing your answer ? I don't see spark.sql.boradcastTimeout in spark documentation...