# Scala - RDD[string] to RDD[vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to stackoverflow. I need help with extracting data in organised form from a "data.txt" file (size:1.84 GB). I'm using scala-2.10.4 and spark-1.1.0.

Contents of the data.txt are in the following pattern

ATOM    00000000        00000004        00000001        17.808  15.749  6.649   -0.548  15.9994

ATOM    00000001    00247690    00000002    20.9489 12.0511 5.4639  0.4238  1.008

There are ~300k atoms in the data.txt file with same pattern and about 286890 atoms in each frame(2nd attribute). i.e., frame 00000000 contains 286890 atoms as well as frame 00000001 contains 286890 atoms.

where the:

- first attribute is just telling whether it is an atom entry or a HEAD entry (there is only one HEAD entry per 
  frame and it has some system property/info)
- second attribute is the "Frame Number"
- third attribute is the "atom ID / number"
- fourth attribute is the "atom type"
- fifth, sixth and seventh attributes are the atom's position vector (x, y, z)
- eight attribute is the atom's charge
- ninth attribute is the atom's mass.

I need to access the data frame by frame and calculate few things from the above data like,

1.Sum of masses of each frame. formula : M = Σmi  (i<- 1 to n)

2.Moment of Inertia. formula : I = Σmiri  (i<- 1 to n)
and a few more similar things.

As you can see, I need to extract the data from data.txt.
I used,

```
  val logFile = "/path/data.txt"
  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
```

logData is an RDD[string], I can only use it to count number of lines with a specific pettern. 
But, I need to get the 7th field of each line(i.e., mass) from every frame to calculate the sum of masses, which I don't know how to do.

*I need to use scala and not allowed to do it any other language.

Please help me know how to do it.
I guess converting it into RDD[vector] would work, but I don't know how to access the specific field from that vector.

Comment: Post what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: You are literally asking some one to code for your problem statement! .

Comment: for such a small file you don't need to use Spark. The code will be simpler as well.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you really need to learn a thing or two about Spark and functional programming before attempting to solve a problem with Spark and especially before posting questions on StackOverflow - as you can see from the comments, people get annoyed when it is clear from a question that no effort has been put into learning the basics before posting.

That said, converting a text/csv file to an `rdd` has been answered before on SO (see for instance [How do I convert csv file to rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd)), so have a look at that. Once you have your `rdd` of type `RDD[Array[String]]`, you simply access the elements the same way you would normally access elements in an array. In the example below, I map each line to a key-value pair to illustrate how you access the elements of the array. I understand, that you need to do some calculations, so you probably need to use another function than `map`, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
val logData: RDD[Array[String]] = sc.textFile("/path/data.txt", 2).map(line => line.split(",") 

logData.map(a => (a.head, (a(1),a(2)))
```

As a last note, I would strongly recommend that you upgrade to the latest version of Spark (1.5.2 at the time of writing this) instead of using a old version like 1.1.0. A lot has changed in Spark since 1.1.0 and packages like spark-csv from Databricks that will parse csv-files for you, are available for newer versions.