# Best way to read TSV file using Apache Spark in java

Tags: java, csv, apache-spark

I have a TSV file, where the first line is the header. I want to create a JavaPairRDD from this file. Currently, I'm doing so with the following code:

```
TsvParser tsvParser = new TsvParser(new TsvParserSettings());
List<String[]> allRows;
List<String> headerRow;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile))) {
        allRows = tsvParser.parseAll((reader));
        //Removes the header row
        headerRow = Arrays.asList(allRows.remove(0));
    }
JavaPairRDD<String, MyObject> myObjectRDD = javaSparkContext
            .parallelize(allRows)
            .mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row[0], myObjectFromArray(row)));
```

I was wondering if there was a way to have the javaSparkContext read and process the file directly instead of splitting the operation into two parts.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [How do I convert csv file to rdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd), because I'm looking for an answer in Java, not Scala.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert csv file to rdd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, because I'm looking for an answer in Java, not Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter","\t")
    .load("cars.csv");

df.select("year", "model").write()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .save("newcars.csv");
```

Comment: I looked into it, and I don't like that there's no simple way to convert a Dataframe to a JavaRDD of custom objects. You have to parse each row manually.

Comment: I'm curious why you would want an RDD over a dataframe in the instance of unique objects requirement. @alexgbelov

Comment: The rest of my logic uses RDD's; I just needed a way to read in the data as cleanly as possible.

Comment: spark 2x implement the function. You don't need spark-csv anymore

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to read CSV file and create JavaPairRDD.

```
public class SparkCSVReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSV Reader");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> allRows = sc.textFile("c:\\temp\\test.csv");//read csv file
    String header = allRows.first();//take out header
    JavaRDD<String> filteredRows = allRows.filter(row -> !row.equals(header));//filter header
    JavaPairRDD<String, MyCSVFile> filteredRowsPairRDD = filteredRows.mapToPair(parseCSVFile);//create pair
    filteredRowsPairRDD.foreach(data -> {
        System.out.println(data._1() + " ### " + data._2().toString());// print row and object
    });
    sc.stop();
    sc.close();
}

private static PairFunction<String, String, MyCSVFile> parseCSVFile = (row) -> {
    String[] fields = row.split(",");
    return new Tuple2<String, MyCSVFile>(row, new MyCSVFile(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2]));
};

}
```

You can also use Databricks spark-csv (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). spark-csv is also included in Spark 2.0.0.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into Databricks spark-csv, but I didn't like it since you'd have to manually parse each row, which I'm already doing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark 2.x have built-in csv reader so you don't have to use  https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

/**
 *
 * @author cpu11453local
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("local")
                .appName("meowingful")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .option("delimiter","\t")
                    .csv("hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/data/meow_data.csv");

        df.show();
    }
}
```

And maven file `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.meow.meowingful</groupId>
    <artifactId>meowingful</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) and can't help you much with spark, but I believe something like this can work for you:

```
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true); //captures the header row

parserSettings.setProcessor(new AbstractRowProcessor(){
        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            String[] headers = context.headers() //not sure if you need them
            JavaPairRDD<String, MyObject> myObjectRDD = javaSparkContext
                    .mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row[0], myObjectFromArray(row)));
            //process your stuff.
        }
    });
```

If you want to paralellize the processing of each row, you can wrap a `ConcurrentRowProcessor`:

```
parserSettings.setProcessor(new ConcurrentRowProcessor(new AbstractRowProcessor(){
        @Override
        public void rowProcessed(String[] row, ParsingContext context) {
            String[] headers = context.headers() //not sure if you need them
            JavaPairRDD<String, MyObject> myObjectRDD = javaSparkContext
                    .mapToPair(row -> new Tuple2<>(row[0], myObjectFromArray(row)));
            //process your stuff.
        }
    }, 1000)); //1000 rows loaded in memory.
```

Then just call to parse:

```
new TsvParser(parserSettings).parse(myFile);
```

Hope this helps!