# Getting data from two csv using spark (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have 2 csv files .

`Employee.csv` with the schema

```
EmpId   Fname   
1       John    
2       Jack    
3       Ram
```

and 2nd csv file as 
Leave.csv

```
EmpId   LeaveType   Designation
1       Sick             SE
1       Casual           SE
2       Sick             SE
3       Privilege         M
1       Casual           SE
2       Privilege        SE
```

Now I want the data in json as

```
EmpID-1 
Sick : 2
Casual : 2
Privilege : 0
```

Using spark in Java

Comment: You have expressed your wish, but you forgot to ask a question. Here we do homework, but rather help with specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping by the column 'LeaveType' and perfoming *count* on them

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count
 val leaves = ??? // Load leaves
 leaves.groupBy(col("LeaveType")).agg(count(col("LeaveType").as("total_leaves")).show()
```

Comment: Can we do it without using Spark Sql

Comment: Yes, the principle is the same. Instead of using columns use key-value pairs

Comment: Can you please help me with it in detail . I am very new to Spark .

Comment: You need to do some reading. Read about parsing CSV in Spark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299427/how-do-i-convert-csv-file-to-rdd and to get the count reduce by key: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#ReduceByLink

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Java syntax but if you do not want to use the dataframe API, you may do something like this in scala,

```
val rdd= sc.textfile("/path/to/leave.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(x=>((x(0),x(1),x(2)),1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

now you need to use some external API like `GSON` to transform each element of this RDD to desired JSON format. Each element of this rdd is a Tuple4, in which there is (EmpId, leaveType, Designation, Countofleaves)

Let me know if this helped, Cheers.

Comment: I dont know scala :P Actually i wanted it in java itself

Comment: they're both JVM based languages, I'm sure the snippet above will give you a hint of what I'm doing.